# System.Net.WebException exception

Tags: asp.net, web-services, database-connection

I  am getting the following exception in my ASP.net project

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
>
> Source Error: Line 76: [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("tempuri.org/GetUserByName";, RequestNamespace="tempuri.org/";, ResponseNamespace="tempuri.org/";, Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)] Line 77: public DTO_User GetUserByName(string name) { Line 78: object[] results = this.Invoke("GetUserByName", new object[] { Line 79: name}); Line 80: return ((DTO_User)(results[0]));

I think that there must be some problem with my connection string but I don't have concrete idea about that.

I am using VS 2010 with sql server management studio where my Database is residing....

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Can you post the complete text of the exception.

Comment: Source Error: 
Line 76:         [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/GetUserByName", RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
Line 77:         public DTO_User GetUserByName(string name) {
Line 78:             object[] results = this.Invoke("GetUserByName", new object[] {
Line 79:                         name});
Line 80:             return ((DTO_User)(results[0]));

Comment: Is this Stack Trace complete??

Could you provide code here.

You can edit your question, for code and stack trace. it will be more helpful.

Answer (score -1):

In general a 404 status means a resource is not found. in this case, most likely it means the page you are trying to access does not exist.